# Viewing/Changing App paths used by `open -a foo.app ...`

Tags: macos, applications, command-line, launch-services

When using `open -a iTerm.app SOMEPATH` from a shell-script or Emacs eshell command, it appears to launch a different instance of iTerm than the one in `/Applications/iTerm.app` that I'd expect.

Explicitly specifying the app path like:

`open -a /Applications/iTerm.app SOMEPATH` works as expected.

This leads me to suspect that there's a lookup table/database somewhere (probably part of LaunchServices) that's mapping bare .app names to an on-disk path, and it's somehow confused as to which it should be using (I do have multiple instance of iTerm on disk, from when I've been playing around with compiling from source. None are in my $PATH, however.)

Any suggestions on how to find what on-disk path an 
`open -a <non-absolute .app name>` will use, and ideally, how it can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

If you type the following commando:

> open -R iTerm.app

it will **reveal** the iTerm.app you're currently selecting in Finder.

If you type

> open -a /applications/iTerm.app

it will open the iTerm.app in the /Applications folder as you said.

If you type

> open -a iTerm.app

it will open iTerm.app in the current location. (you can type **ls** to see the contents of the current folder, or use the above method (**-R**)

As a general hint, please type

> open --help

to see the methods/commands available you can use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the `-R` option (and have in fact, read the manpage `;)`), but `open -R iTerm.app` fails with "The file /iTerm.app does not exist." `-R` with an absolute path does indeed reveal it, but still leaves me not knowing what's happening in the non-absolute case.